# Use Autofac for webform and web api same app

Tags: webforms, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I use web api and webform in same project
In webform, we can use page_unload to dispose scope.
How to release scope in web api, when a request complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your assumption about web forms use - you don't dispose of the scope on `Page_Unload`. You should be using [the web forms integration as documented here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html) which would put some HttpModule implementations in your pipeline to automatically dispose of the scope at the right time (`End_Request`).

You can use the [Web API integration as documented here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html) in the same application and things will work just fine together. The Web API integration will automatically handle disposing of the scope for you.